# Deleting node from Linear Linked List recursively C++

Tags: recursion

I'm trying to write a function to delete a node any where in a linear linked list recursively but it's not working so far. Deleting at the beginning works but not in the middle. Here is my code

```
int remove(node* &head, char* data_to_delete)
{ 
  if(!head) return 0; // check if head is null

  if(!strcmp(head->data,data_to_delete)) //check if the first node is data
  { node* temp  = head->next;  //save head->next
    delete [] head->data;  //deallocate data 
    delete head; //delete the node
    head = temp;  //connect the node 
    return 1;
  }

  if(head->next && !strcmp(head->next->data,data_to_delete))//check if head->next is not null and head->next->data is equal to data
  {
      node* temp = head->next->next; 
      delete [] head->next->data;
      delete head->next;
      head->next = temp;
      return 1;
  }
  remove(head->next, data_to_delete);
}
```

Also how would I modify this if I want to drag along a previous pointer instead of looking ahead? Thanks!!!!

Comment: It appears to me that you can reach the end of this function without returning a value. On recursive calls to remove, those remove functions end, and you are kicked out at the bottom of the function, right after the recursive call.  Perhaps you can return remove(head->next, data_to_delete); instead of just calling the function.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.